# Tidymodels: How to extract importance from training data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, tidymodels

I have the following code, where I do some grid search for different mtry and min_n. I know how to extract the parameters that give the highest accuracy (see second code box). How can I extract the importance of each feature in the training dataset? The guides I found online show how to do it only in the test dataset using "last_fit". E.g. of guide: https://www.tidymodels.org/start/case-study/#data-split

```
set.seed(seed_number)
    data_split <- initial_split(node_strength,prop = 0.8,strata = Group)
    
    train <- training(data_split)
    test <- testing(data_split)
    train_folds <- vfold_cv(train,v = 10)
    
    
    rfc <- rand_forest(mode = "classification", mtry = tune(),
                       min_n = tune(), trees = 1500) %>%
        set_engine("ranger", num.threads = 48, importance = "impurity")
    
    rfc_recipe <- recipe(data = train, Group~.)
    
    rfc_workflow <- workflow() %>% add_model(rfc) %>%
        add_recipe(rfc_recipe)
    
    rfc_result <- rfc_workflow %>%
        tune_grid(train_folds, grid = 40, control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE),
                  metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
```

.

```
best <- 
        rfc_result %>% 
        select_best(metric = "accuracy")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this, you will want to create a custom `extract` function, as [outlined in this documentation](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/coefficients/).

For random forest variable importance, your function will look something like this:

```r
get_rf_imp <- function(x) {
    x %>% 
        extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
        vip::vi()
}
```

And then you can apply it to your resamples like so (notice that you get a new `.extracts` column):

```r
library(tidymodels)
data(cells, package = "modeldata")

set.seed(123)
cell_split <- cells %>% select(-case) %>%
    initial_split(strata = class)
cell_train <- training(cell_split)
cell_test  <- testing(cell_split)
folds <- vfold_cv(cell_train)            

rf_spec <- rand_forest(mode = "classification") %>%
    set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")

ctrl_imp <- control_grid(extract = get_rf_imp)

cells_res <-
    workflow(class ~ ., rf_spec) %>%
    fit_resamples(folds, control = ctrl_imp)
cells_res
#> # Resampling results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>    splits             id     .metrics         .notes           .extracts       
#>    <list>             <chr>  <list>           <list>           <list>          
#>  1 <split [1362/152]> Fold01 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  2 <split [1362/152]> Fold02 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  3 <split [1362/152]> Fold03 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  4 <split [1362/152]> Fold04 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  5 <split [1363/151]> Fold05 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  6 <split [1363/151]> Fold06 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  7 <split [1363/151]> Fold07 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  8 <split [1363/151]> Fold08 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#>  9 <split [1363/151]> Fold09 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
#> 10 <split [1363/151]> Fold10 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Once you have those variable importance score extracts, you can `unnest()` them (right now, you have to do this twice because it is deeply nested) and then you can summarize and visualize as you prefer:

```r
cells_res %>%
    select(id, .extracts) %>%
    unnest(.extracts) %>%
    unnest(.extracts) %>%
    group_by(Variable) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(Importance),
              Variance = sd(Importance)) %>%
    slice_max(Mean, n = 15) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Mean, reorder(Variable, Mean))) +
    geom_crossbar(aes(xmin = Mean - Variance, xmax = Mean + Variance)) +
    labs(x = "Variable importance", y = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>