# Permutation based variable importance (violin) plots for random forest in Tidy models

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels, vip

I have built a random forest tidy model very similar to what Julia Silge has done in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYaNdxmlYUg&t=2209s). I also plan to show variable importance plots based on the permutation method, however I would like to show box plots or violin plots, rather than points.

Here is an example, [following Julia's code](https://juliasilge.com/blog/water-sources/):

**Data and Model Building**

```
# DATA
library(tidyverse)
water_raw <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-05-04/water.csv")

# Data prep
water <- water_raw %>%
  filter(
    country_name == "Sierra Leone",
    lat_deg > 0, lat_deg < 15, lon_deg < 0,
    status_id %in% c("y", "n")
  ) %>%
  mutate(pay = case_when(
    str_detect(pay, "^No") ~ "no",
    str_detect(pay, "^Yes") ~ "yes",
    is.na(pay) ~ pay,
    TRUE ~ "it's complicated"
  )) %>%
  select(-country_name, -status, -report_date) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)


library(tidymodels)

set.seed(123)
water_split <- initial_split(water, strata = status_id)
water_train <- training(water_split)
water_test <- testing(water_split)

set.seed(234)
water_folds <- vfold_cv(water_train, strata = status_id)
water_folds


# Model building
library(themis)
ranger_recipe <-
  recipe(formula = status_id ~ ., data = water_train) %>%
  update_role(row_id, new_role = "id") %>%
  step_unknown(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_other(all_nominal_predictors(), threshold = 0.03) %>%
  step_impute_linear(install_year) %>%
  step_downsample(status_id)

ranger_spec <-
  rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

ranger_workflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(ranger_recipe) %>%
  add_model(ranger_spec)

doParallel::registerDoParallel()
set.seed(74403)
ranger_rs <-
  fit_resamples(ranger_workflow,
    resamples = water_folds,
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
  )
```

**Here is Julia's VIP code:**

```
library(vip)

imp_data <- ranger_recipe %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) %>%
  select(-row_id)


ranger_spec %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation") %>%
  fit(status_id ~ ., data = imp_data) %>%
  vip(geom = "point")
```

[Julia's VIP w points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xTly.png)

**My Attempt:**

```
ranger_spec %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation") %>%
  fit(status_id ~ ., data = imp_data) %>%
  vip(pred_wrapper = predict, geom = "boxplot", nsim = 10, keep = TRUE)
```

However it continues to return this error:

Error: To construct boxplots for permutation-based importance scores you must specify `keep = TRUE` in the call `vi()` or `vi_permute()`. Additionally, you also need to set `nsim >= 2`.

Because I have done all of those things, I assume my error is with pred_wrapper, but I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks ya'll!

Answer (score 2):

First, you may be interested in a [resampling approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72538064/tidymodels-how-to-extra-importance-from-training-data/72680901#72680901) to estimating variable importance, where you yourself control the resampling and what gets extracted.

Second, I think something is not working quite right with `method = "permutation"` for a tidymodels model. I can't get it to work, but I can get the permutation importance  for the underlying model:

```r
library(vip)

imp_data <- ranger_recipe %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) %>%
  select(-row_id)

mod <- ranger::ranger(status_id ~ ., data = imp_data, classification = TRUE)

pred_fun = function(object, newdata) {
  predict(object, newdata)$predictions
}

vip(mod, method = "permute",
    train = imp_data, target = "status_id", 
    metric = "accuracy", pred_wrapper = pred_fun)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[Here is another resource for how to use vip](http://xai-tools.drwhy.ai/vip.html), but you may want to look into using [DALEX for permutation variable importance](https://www.tmwr.org/explain.html#global-explanations).

Comment: I can confirm that [vip works for regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772397/integration-of-variable-importance-plots-within-the-tidy-modelling-framework/62962550#62962550); I am only having trouble with classification.

Comment: I [opened this issue](https://github.com/koalaverse/vip/issues/131) to see if we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hi @Julia Silge, thanks for this solution. I am playing with a resampling approach as you suggested, but it continues to return the error: Error in workflow(class ~ ., rf_spec) : 
  unused arguments (class ~ ., rf_spec). Running the code in the link you provided as is also returns this error. I wonder if there is an issue with extract_fit_parsnip()? Or am i missing some dependencies? Thanks!